# Download activity unfortunately stopped

Tags: android

I am testing an app that downloads on button click. But the app crashes . the logcat says you have to use them.appcompat.  but I use theme.material.light. how to fix this?

**main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnShowProgress;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView my_image;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 

// File url to download
private static String file_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/progressdialog/hive.jpg";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // show progress bar button
    btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
    // Image view to show image after downloading
    my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    /**
     * Show Progress bar click event
     * */
    btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting new Async Task
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            }
        });
}

/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        // Displaying downloaded image into image view
        // Reading image path from sdcard
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        // setting downloaded into image view
        my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

  }
 }
```

**android manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myapp2" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Permission: Writing to SDCard -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**logcat**

```
    12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 10939

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)

12-04 15:03:51.086 10939 10939 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to use **AppCompat Theme**.

Your **style.xml** should looks like below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!-- other stuff -->

</style>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah that worked but what if I want to use it with theme.material.light. thanks a lot

Comment: @user5524159, thanks for appreciation, you can extends Activity instead of AppCompatActivity.

Comment: How can I use it with material.light theme. Help me

Answer (score 1):

The Current Theme you are using is for Activity Class

because you have changed it to AppCompatActivity you need to use

Theme supported by AppCompatActivity.

Just customise your **AppTheme** from **style.xml** and it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped me a lot